# mule3 retry policy for HTTP

Tags: http, mule, esb

I want to set a retry policy for HTTP call, in case of occasional network failuer, So I configured as following:

```
    <http:connector name="HTTP_Retry" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
      <reconnect frequency="1000" count="3"/>
</http:connector>
....
<http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:18081/mule/TheCreditAgencyService" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" connector-ref="HTTP_Retry"/>
```

But the retry policy is not applied, even I configured a customer retry policy, I debuged the application, set break point, the program is not run into my customer class.

I read the document but there is only example of JMS.

Any tips? Do I miss configured?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ill-named retry policies take care of reconnecting connectors not resending messages in case of failure.

On a disconnected connector like the HTTP one, a retry policy has not effect. It's useful on connectors like JMS, where a permanent connection is maintained towards a broker, connection that needs reconnecting in case of failure.

What you are after is the [until-successful routing message processor](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-UntilSuccessful).

Comment: Thanks, but is a async process, is there a sync process retry?

Comment: You can simulate a sync retry by using a VM or JMS queue redelivery with transactions. But why do you need a sync process?

Comment: I want to retry for network issue, say 3 times and the request is hold on. BTW, how to get the result of async process?

Comment: What request are you holding on? An incoming HTTP request? The result is available in the processor-chain/sub-flow/private flow that is retried by the until-successful, right after the potentially failing outbound HTTP endpoint. If you need to share this result with another thread, you can use a request-reply router.